# Create binary numbers with a described pattern

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, combinatorics, binary, bit-manipulation

I am looking for an algorithm that can create binary numbers following certain patterns. Let $n$ be the size; and assume that is a power of 2. Let $E$ be the exponent; $n = 2^E; k = \log n$. The $0, 1$ on the "top level" are symbols, and let $0^n, 1^n$ represent $n$ consecutive zeroes and ones respectively.

- For size 2, $E = 1$, and the one number is given by $0^1 1^1 = 01$.
- For size 4, $E = 2$, and the two numbers are $0^2 1^2 = (0^2 1^2)^1 = 0011$ and $(0^1 1^1)^2 = 0101$.
- For size 8, $E = 3$, and the three numbers are $(0^4 1^4)^1 = 00001111$, $(0^2 1^2)^2 = 00110011$, $(0^1 1^1)^4 = 01010101$.
- For size $n = 2^E$, the $E$ numbers include $(0^1 1^1)^{n/2} = (0^{2^0} 1^{2^0})^{2^{E-1}}$ to $(0^{n/2} 1^{n/2})^1 = (0^{2^{E-1}} 1^{2^{E-1}})^{2^{0}}$. Thus, the $E$ numbers can be parameterized by a natural number $k$ from 0 to $E-1$ such that the member is expressible as $(0^{2^k} 1^{2^k})^{2^{(E-1)-k}}$.

Is there an algorithm using bit manipulation that can generate each of these numbers in the set with algorithm in the range of $O(1)$ to $O(n)$?

**Important Note:** I am looking for an algorithm that generates binary numbers not strings unless transformation from strings to binary numbers can be in the range of $O(1)$ to $O(n)$.

Comment: The desired pattern wasn't clear to me from the examples.  I generally don't find examples to be a good substitute for a clear, general specification of the problem.  As such, I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve or what you are asking.

Comment: This requires a family of regexes.

Comment: @D.W We can create a sequence of sets.
For size 2 strings we have 0^1 1^1.
For size 4 strings we have (0^1 1^1)^1 or 0^2 1^2.
For size n strings we have (0^k 1^k)^(n-k)

Comment: @D.W. The question has been updated more

Comment: You write $n=2^E$ and $k=\log n$ (presumably base $2$). So $k=E$ ???

Comment: The binary numbers have a number of bits that is linear in $n$. Hence the complexity is certainly $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: **Important note**: computers do not support binary numbers with arbitrary length. State of the art is 64 bits. (`BigNums` are not binary numbers, they are arrays of numbers.)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the size; and assume that is a power of 2. Let $E$ be the exponent; $n = 2^E; k = \log n$. The $0, 1$ on the "top level" are symbols, and let $0^n, 1^n$ represent $n$ consecutive zeroes and ones respectively.

- For size 2, $E = 1$, and the one string is given by $0^1 1^1 = 01$.
- For size 4, $E = 2$, and the two strings are $0^2 1^2 = (0^2 1^2)^1 = 0011$ and $(0^1 1^1)^2 = 0101$.
- For size 8, $E = 3$, and the three strings are $(0^4 1^4)^1 = 00001111$, $(0^2 1^2)^2 = 00110011$, $(0^1 1^1)^4 = 01010101$.
- For size $n = 2^E$, the $E$ strings include $(0^1 1^1)^{n/2} = (0^{2^0} 1^{2^0})^{2^{E-1}}$ to $(0^{n/2} 1^{n/2})^1 = (0^{2^{E-1}} 1^{2^{E-1}})^{2^{0}}$. Thus, the $E$ strings can be parameterized by a natural number $k$ from 0 to $E-1$ such that the member is expressible as $(0^{2^k} 1^{2^k})^{2^{(E-1)-k}}$.

Thus, the examples are:

- Size 2: $E = 1$. The one string is $(0^1 1^1)^1 = (0^{2^0}1^{2^0})^{2^0}$
- Size 4: $E = 2$. The two strings are $0101 = (0^1 1^1)^2 = (0^{2^0} 1^{2^0})^{2^1}$ and $0011 = (0^2 1^2)^1 = (0^{2^1} = 1^{2^1})^{2^0}$.
- Size 8: $E = 3$. The three strings are $01010101 = (0^{2^0} 1^{2^0})^{2^2}$ with $k = 0$, $00110011 = (0^{2^1} 1^{2^1})^{2^1}$ with $k = 1$, $00001111 = (0^{2^2} 1^{2^2})^{2^0}$ with $k = 2$.

This is an iterative algorithm. You list each string, of length $n$ a total of $\log n$ times. It is $O(n \log n)$ to list all the strings explicity. It is $O(\log n)$ to express them regex style like $(0^x 1^x)^y$ [note $x, y$ are powers of 2, and the exponents in the power form of $x, y$ add up to $E-1$].

Comment: Thanks for explaining the question better. Questions: 1. How is it (log) to generate each of the strings? 2. Is there any pseudo generation algorithm for this using bit manipulation? 3. In case of generation of all possible combinations with iteration, shouldn't the time complexity be (log*log) if expressing each of them is (log)?

Comment: Good catch. I assume if the exponents are comst lengtb.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment, binary numbers of size $n$ are not supported by current computers. We have two situations:

- only support the native binary type; as $n$ does not exceed $64$, you can very well precompute all patterns and store them in an array. (Counting all feasible sizes, there would be $2016$ patterns.)
- allow BigNums made of a sequence of $64$ bits integers; this is a little more tricky; you need to distinguish the case of inner patterns of length $\le64$ and $>64$. But the basic principle is simple: generate the inner pattern and replicate it as many times as needed. You can't avoid an exhaustive construction.